# What is this "full fruit"?

Tags: isaiah, niv

In Isaiah 27:9 (NIV)

> By this, then, will Jacob's guilt be atoned for, and this will be the **full fruit** of the removal of his sin: When he makes all the altar stones to be like limestone crushed to pieces, no Asherah poles or incense altars will be left standing.

We can read about "full fruit" to take away the sin of Israel. What is this "full fruit"?

Answer (score 1):

The whole verse of Isa 29:9 reads:

> Therefore Jacob’s guilt will be atoned for, and the full fruit of the
> removal of his sin will be this: When he makes all the altar stones
> like crushed bits of chalk, no Asherah poles or incense altars will
> remain standing.

The "full fruit" of the removal of Jacob's sin is:

- the altar stones will become like crushed bits of chalk
- no Asherah poles or incense altars will remain standing

This is simply saying that the result (= "fruit") of the removal of Jacob's sin of idolatry is the removal of all the pagan altars and Asherah poles (phallic symbols of pagan worship) from the land.

Benson says it this way:

> Which sin of Jacob shall be taken away, and the punishment thereof
> removed, when he shall give such an evidence of the reality of his
> repentance as to destroy all the objects, instruments, means, and
> signs of idolatry out of the land; when he maketh the stones of the
> altar — Namely, the idolatrous altar, or altars, as chalk-stones —
> That is, broken into small pieces, and reduced to powder and dust.

Ellicott also has a similar idea:

> This is all the fruit to take away his sin.—Better, of taking away his
> sin. The words repeat the thought of the previous clause. The fruit of
> repentance and forgiveness will be found in rooting out all vestiges
> of idol-worship. The LXX., “when I shall take away their sins,” is
> quoted by St. Paul in Romans 11:27.
>
> The groves and images.—Literally, as elsewhere, the Asherahs, or the
> sun-images, the two leading features of the cultus which Israel had
> borrowed from the Phœnicians. In the action of Josiah (2Chronicles
> 34:3-4) we may, with little doubt, trace a conscious endeavour to
> fulfil the condition which Isaiah had thus proclaimed. He sought to
> “purge” Judah and Jerusalem from the “groves and the carved (sun)
> images, and molten images.”